# "How do you want to open this file?" when running kubectl or minikube commands

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to run some kubectl commands like

```
kubectl get nodes
kubectl get pods
```

or to start a minikube cluster with `minikube start`, but whatever command I run from Windows Powershell, instead of getting a proper output I get whe Windows window asking me "How do you want to open this file?".
I have tried uninstalling and re-installing minikube, kubernetes-cli and Docker, but I had no luck. How can I solve?

Comment: have you added the environment variable `kube`?

Comment: I haven't, but after I installed kubelet the first time, it worked. It suddenly started to act weird however

Answer (score 0):

Try in PowerShell:
PS C:> Set-Alias -Name kubectl -Value kubectl.exe

Or
Download kubectl.exe
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/

then put into C:\windows\system32
Since that path is already registered in system Env Variables it should work.

If you prefer a different path, create/put the file there and set up a System Environment variable PATH

Answer (score 0):

You need to open C:\Windows\System32 and delete kubectl file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).